# Team Foundation Service not available (TFS2008)

Tags: tfs

We have had an automatic Active Directory/Windows password change thrust upon us, and consequently our TFS2008 build server has broken. I have changed the password for the TFSERVICE account it runs under, and updated the Visual Studio Team Foundation Task Scheduler Service to use the correct password, and checked that the underlying Sql Server is running okay. However attempts to connect to TFS are now met with the message '..HTO Status 503: Service unavailable'.

What else needs to be started to get this up and running again?

Comment: A 503 HTTP response is not an authentication failure normally. Do you need to restart a process on the TFS server? Usually you'll get 503 responses when you've got hung threads on the server and no more available in that app pool.

Comment: Server has been restarted several times and all the services seem to be running normally.

Comment: Looking at the MS documentation, it refers to two services I cannot see - Reporting Web Service and Sharepoint Services. These aren't listed under the Services tool, although we use reporting and Sharepoint as part of Team System. Any ideas on which services they are?

Comment: It may be the TFS web site. Try to check IIS AppPool (and particularly Identity that runs AppPool).

Comment: Did you change the passwords directly on the services or did you use the TFS Admin Console?

Comment: We changed passwords directly, but then used the TFSAdmin command to do it again and that seemed to fix the problem. The AppPool was not running either (or at least kept stopping) which did not help, but it all seems well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to always change the password using the tools in the box. You can use the TFS Administration Console that you can launch from the start menu. Or you can use the tfsconfig.exe located in the TFS install folder.

This applies to all versions of TFS from 2010 on.

If you have TFS 2008/2005 you will need to use the tfsadminutil command: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552178(v=vs.90).aspx

Note: You need to upgrade your TFS server as soon as possible. Both the OS, SQL, and TFS pre-2010 is not well supported.

Comment: sadly no TFS Administration Console available from the Start menu. Is that available for TFS 2008?

Comment: Indeed it is. You need to log onto the server that is running tfs.

Comment: I was! Sadly no TFS Administration Console available from the Start menu

Comment: Then TFS is not installed. This console is always present.

Comment: I assure you that it (TFS2008) is installed - and has been working for several years, and yet I cannot find anything in the TFS server start menu purporting to be a TFS Administration Console. According to msdn it is not provided as part of TFS2008 - only TFS2010 onwards.

Comment: Updated to reflect ... Its been 5 years since I used 2008 for anything but upgrade fodder...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. We are indeed upgrading to TFS2013, as soon as we can fit it in! Problem now solved too.